# moveit joint with more than 2pi rotation

Tags: ros, moveit, joints, limits

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey,
i was wondering if im doing something wrong or if moveit cant handle revolute joints which surpass -2pi/2pi. im extending an ur5 with a contiunous joint and moveit automatically limits it to -pi/pi. However if i declare the joint as revolute with some generous limits like -10pi/10pi the planning fails or gives terrible results. Is there any way to fix this problem?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268375/moveit-joint-with-more-than-2pi-rotation/) by [lbalog](https://answers.ros.org/users/31495/lbalog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can handle continuous or less-limited revolute joints but.

Continuous joints are handled differently from limited joints.
Solutions are always given in [-pi;pi] but can wrap around when needed.
For execution the generated trajectories can actually `unwind` and give
waypoints outside [-pi;pi].

If you encounter a specific problem here please report it in the github
repository.

Simulating continuous joints by larger rotation limits is a bad idea.
The biggest problem is that you increase the search space tremendously which is probably why planning times out.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsather](https://answers.ros.org/users/34427/jsather/) on 2018-04-12**:
Do you know if the 'unwind' feature is implemented in the compute_cartesian_path method? Moveit seems to be ignoring waypoints following a -pi to pi (or vice versa) wrap-around in any of the robot joints.

**Comment by [LorenzS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40805/lorenzs/) on 2019-04-10**:
Hello,
i have a simular problem. I am working with a KUKA robot which has joint limits of +/-190 degrees. If the robot moves to a position where the limits overlap, it gets trapped there.

Is there a posibility to use revolute joints with limits over +/-pi?
Thanks